# Hover function in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, hover

I have *four* **`li div`** that have inside a link of an image (*so they're four links and four images*), but I can't understand why the hover function doesn't work here .

The error is :

> element.hover isn't a function:

```
var element =$("li div")
var element_link = element.find("a");
var element_img = element.find("img");
element_img.css("opacity","0.5");
element_link.each(function(index, element) {
    element.hover(
    function(){element_img[index].animate({opacity:1}),250},
    function(){element_img[index].animate({opacity:0.5}),250}
    );
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you forgot to close .`animate` function properly, should be like this `animate({opacity:1},250);`

Comment: `element` inside each loop isn't a jQuery object because you are redefining it but a DOM node element, hasn't get any `hover` method. Use e.g: `$(element).hover(...)`

Comment: @SalvatoreEsposito you are redefining it here `.each(function(index, element)` then see DOC: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `each()` on a collection of jQuery elements. You can simply use the following code to apply the hover to all of the `element_link`s:

```
element_link.hover(
  function(){$(this).siblings('img').animate({opacity:1}),250},
  function(){$(this).siblings('img').animate({opacity:0.5}),250}
);
```

Comment: But in this wat How can it use the index?

Comment: @SalvatoreEsposito Ok sorry didn't seen the difference between `element_link` & `element_img`, my bad

Comment: @SalvatoreEsposito good one, I overlooked that. I edited the answer so that it doesn't require index (and also not the element_link array)

Comment: Yeah, it's my fault, cause you can see the html code. But in my code they're in different divs so they're not siblings. But I suppose your code works only if the <a> and <img> are at the same level, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

I solved in this way:

```
var element =$("li div");
var element_link = element.find("a");
var element_img = element.find("img");
element_img.css("opacity","0.5");

element_link.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(
   function(){$(element_img[index]).animate({opacity:1},250)},
   function(){$(element_img[index]).animate({opacity:0.5},250)}
);
});
```

Thank to Wolf and Amit too( there were an error in animate function too).